# Use .net server have question for ubuntu16.04

Tags: .net, ubuntu

My system is ubuntu 16.04 server, the server to run a company. The net core server program, the port is 10240, but by other computer client connection is not on my side, ufw firewall configuration also useless, disable it would be useless. And then through the Telnet port, the result see the pictures, I am now can't find the reason. And netstat NTLP results

netstat NTLP:
[image: netstat NTLP]

Telnet port:
[image: Telnet port]

Comment: What excactly is your problem/question?

Comment: I deployed the server on ubuntu, using port 10240,But my client doesn't connect.I want to know if there are any problems with my setup.thanks